# Android: fused location provider on ice cream sandwich 4.0

Tags: android

I'm writing an app that logs my location to a database. Currently I'm using the location manager service provided by android.

I am thinking of shifting to using fused location provider however I would would want to know if ice cream sandwich supports this api or will only android kitkat will have this feature.

Also I'd like to know if gingerbread supports it if I have Google play services installed on my phone

Thanks 
Sahil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fused Location API is implemented in the [com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html) class, which is part of the [Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html). These are available on every device with Android version 2.3+ and the Google Play Store app.

Comment: I just wanted to ask does the native LocationManager class in android also use the Google play services to get their location

Comment: No, it's part of the SDK since API lvl 1.